# How to use R to send an image to Power Automate

Tags: r, power-automate

I am trying to use R to send an image to Power Automate, which will then send the image as as attachment in an email.

My method is to serialize the image and base-64 encode it as below.

```r
library(magick)
library(tidyverse)

img <- 
  image_read('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png') %>% 
  image_resize('20') # make the image smaller for readability


# serialize and then base 64 encode image
img_encoded <-
  img %>% 
    image_data() %>% 
    serialize(connection = NULL) %>% 
    jsonlite::base64_enc()

img_encoded
#> [1] "WAoAAAADAAQBAwADBQAAAAAGQ1AxMjUyAAADGAAAAjBChfQvQoX0oEKF9K1ChfSiQoX0I0KF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\nAAQCAAAAAQAEAAkAAAADZGltAAAADQAAAAMAAAAEAAAAFAAAAAcAAAD+"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Then I send a POST request to Power Automate like below.

```r
# url to send data
post_url <- REDACTED

# build request body
json_body <- 
  glue::glue(
    '{"subject":"send_email", "data":"~img_encoded^"}',
    .open =  '~',
    .close = '^'
  )

# send response
response <- 
  POST(
    url = post_url, 
    body = json_body,
    content_type('application/json')
  )
```

Then I created the following Power Automate flow, but the email that it sends contains an invalid image.  I think the step I am missing is deserializing the base64-encoded JSON, but I am not able to figure out how to decode it in Power Automate.  Any help is very much appreciated.

[image]